# send Uploaded image data to node server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, image-uploading, multer

I am working with node.js and testing how to upload an image after I click the plus glyphicon (image below). How can I send the chosen image to the server? I uploaded images before, but that was within a form that handled the post request. Afterwrds I would handle it with Multer on the server side. Here I don't know what to do after picking an image as profile picture. I was thinking about $.post in the `imageIsLoaded()` function , but I don't know what to add as the data.

I am able to change the src attribute in the example I give below, but I want to save the chosen image permanently on the server.

[This is how the website looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmGdq.png)

Client side JS file

```
$("#upload").on('click',function() {
    $("input[type='file']").click();
});

$(":file").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});

function imageIsLoaded (e) {
    console.log('heloooooo')
    $('.profileImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

**EJS**

```
<div class="profileImgSection">
        <% if (user.profilePicture.uploaded === false) { %>
        <span id="upload" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        <input type='file'  />

        <img class="profileImg"
             src="<%="images/pexels-photo-370799.jpeg"%>"
             alt="fail">
        <% } else { %>
        <img class="profileImg"
             src="<%=user.profilePicture.link%>"
             alt="fail">
        <% } %>
    </div>
```

CSS file

```
input[type='file'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preview image and upload via ajax when file selector change,
HTML

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
</form>
<img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

JS

```
 function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#preview')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

                //ajax post here
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: new FormData($('#form')[0])
                  }).done(function (data) {

                  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                  });
            }
        }
```